# Defining a constant in terms of other constants

Tags: c

sorry if this question seems naive, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer to it anywhere. I must define a constant in terms of previously defined constants, like

```
#define CONST_A 2
#define CONST_B 3
#define CONST_C CONST_A*CONST_B
```

The actual values of `CONST_A` and `CONST_B` are fed as defineflags to gcc, so I can't just write `#define CONST_C 6`.

If I understand correctly, this will tell the preprocessor to replace any appearance of `CONST_C` by `2*3` and not `6`, right? I'm mainly worried about performance, so I would prefer the latter. I'm guessing this could be done by using `static const` instead of preprocessor `#define`. Is this the best option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Macros don't affect performance.They are evaluated by pre-processor.

Comment: @AlokSave That is actually false; the pre-processor will not replace `CONST_C` with `2*3`, not with `6`.

Comment: @user4815162342: My comment was meant in a general sense which OP seemed to misunderstand. Worrying about performance of `2*3` is red herring & an attempt at over-zealous pre-optimization at best.

Comment: Agreed, but the wording "*evaluated* by the pre-processor" is misleading because it sounds like it's the preprocessor that evaluates the expression, whereas the preprocessor in the end just replaces text with other text.

Comment: @user4815162342, I believe you have one 'not' too many in "the pre-processor will not replace CONST_C with 2*3, not with 6." I'm assuming it should read "the pre-processor will replace CONST_C with 2*3, not with 6." Have I got that right?

Comment: @MathieuK. Correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry about performance of constant expressions like `2 * 3` in C. C compilers have been able to eliminate such expressions by evaluating them at compile-time for at least 20 years.

`static const` can be preferred for other reasons, such as type-safety or not having to worry about precedence (think what happens if `CONST_A` is defined as `2+2`), but not for performance reasons.

Comment: Ok, that was quick! Thanks! So I guess even writing CONST_A*CONST_B in the code will be optimized away by the compiler. That was easy!

Comment: Exactly. If you're feeling adventorous, you can easily verify this by inspecting the assembly output (on Linux, this is done by specifying the `-S` to `gcc` and inspecting the resulting `.S` file).

Answer (score 0):

C say that constant expressions can be evaluated at compile time and any today's decent compiler will evaluate constant expressions at compile time. This compiler operation is known as *constant folding*.

> (C99, 6.6p2) "A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be."